# How to take one Financial year in java

Tags: java, string

How do I change the value of the Year(2014) i.e. from March -December the value of the year is `2014` and after December(2014) the value of the year should change to Year+1 i.e. `2015` in java?

currently I'm doing like the below piece of code

```
String monthsArray[] = { "Apr","May", "Jun", "July", "Aug",    
                         "Sep", "Oct","Nov", "Dec",
                         "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" };

for (int m = 0; m < monthsArray.length; m++) {
    int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
    if (m == 9) {
        yearInt = yearInt + 1;
    }
    if (m >= 9) {
        year = Integer.toString(yearInt);
        accountsBean.setYear(year);
    } else {
        accountsBean.setYear(year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you asked your question right? The default calendar acts the same as you want: In year 2014 from March to December, year is 2014, then after the December(2014) the year is 2015 because you are actually in 2015 after the December. No adjustment needed. Maybe you are about calculating a Fiscal year which is start from March, right? From March 2014 to the end of February of 2015, you want the year to be 2014, Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want it that way. From March 2014 to the end of February 2015 I want it to be 2014. How do i do that? Can you please help?

Comment: It's simple. You can check the `month` of the `Date` object you have. If the `month` was one of the `January` or `February` you `return year-1`, else you `return year`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to append year(s) to a date:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(randomDate);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // add 1 year to randomDate
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Java 8 with the new `java.time` APIs, it is easy to directly query any compatible temporal object for the "fiscal year":

```
private static int fiscalYear(TemporalAccessor val) {
    final int natYear = val.get(ChronoField.YEAR);
    final boolean beforeMarch = Month.from(val).compareTo(Month.MARCH) < 0;
    return natYear - (beforeMarch ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Here, TemporalAccessor is a "generalized" temporal object, which might be a completely defined point in the timeline like OffsetDateTime or a more "fuzzy" object such as LocalDate. You can then use the function as an implementation of the TemporalQuery interface:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().query(fiscalYear)); // Prints 2016
```

It will only work with TemporalAccessor objects that can provide year and month values, so for example the following attempts would raise an exception:

```
// Instant counts nanoseconds from the epoch, but does now know "years" or "months"
System.out.println(Instant.now().query(fiscalYear));
// LocalTime does not store date information at all
System.out.println(LocalTime.now().query(fiscalYear));
```